# Close modal from child inner component

Tags: angular

I have a header component which contains a modal window triggered on click

```
<a (click)="open(content)" class="in">Sign in</a>
<ng-template #content let-modal>
  <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="modal.dismiss('Cross click')">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <app-login></app-login>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

I have a child component (app-login) with a form and a button :

```
<button [disabled]="loading" class="btn btn-primary">
    <span *ngIf="loading" class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm mr-1"></span>
    Login
</button>
```

My issue is that once i am logged, the modal remains opened. I am using ng bootstrap for this app.

Here is the LoginComponent ts file. This class allows to build and validate fields of the form and also to make a redirection :

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
   // ... variables declarations

  constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    private authenticationService: AuthenticationService
  ) {
    if (this.authenticationService.currentUserValue) {
      this.router.navigate(['/']);
    }
  }

  get f() { return this.loginForm.controls; }

  onSubmit() {
    ...
  }
}
```

And here my header component where my modal is opened. it contains 2 methods :

```
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
   // ... variables declarations    
  constructor(private modalService: NgbModal) {}

  open(content) {
    this.modalService.open(content, {ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-basic-title'}).result.then((result) => {
      this.closeResult = `Closed with: ${result}`;
    }, (reason) => {
      this.closeResult = `Dismissed ${this.getDismissReason(reason)}`;
    });
  }    
  private getDismissReason(reason: any): string {
    if (reason === ModalDismissReasons.ESC) {
      return 'by pressing ESC';
    } ...
  }
}
```

Comment: can you add also the ts files? Cause with ng bootstrap there is more method for opening/closing modal

Answer (score 1):

In the child component, handle the ng-bootstrap (close) event:

```
(close)="onModalClose()"
```

And in the typescript emit that event:

```
close: EventEmitter<void> = new EventEmitter<void>();

onModalClose(): void {
  this.close.emit();
}
```

And then handle the child's close event in your parent:

```
(close)="onClose()"
```

And hide the modal in your typescript:

```
onClose(): void {
  this.showModal = false;
}
```

Where showModal is used to determine whether or not the modal should be open.

Answer (score 1):

This line
`close: EventEmitter<void> = new EventEmitter<void>();`

should be
`@Output() close: EventEmitter<void> = new EventEmitter<void>();`